# How to make regex pattern for some scenarios

Tags: java, regex, parsing, pattern-matching, regex-group

Am doing WordXml parsar using JAVA.

And now i want to check `(F(1) = 44)` this type of pattern will be occured or not in a paragraph.

**Note:** Inside of open close will have must integer value.

Folloing pattern i will need to check.

```
(text text (text) text)
(F(1) = 44)
(text text [text] text)
[text text (text) text]
```

But, Clearly don't know how to make regex pattern for above the senarios.

So, Please suggest me. And anybody pls let me know.

Comment: try something out at https://regex101.com/

Comment: "Can someone do this for me ?" is th perfect that shows that you don't jnow where you are, SO does not provide code, it helps on what you did

Comment: Use `str.contains("(F(1) = 44)")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex `\([a-zA-Z]+\(\d+\)\s*=\s*\d+\)`, which mean

- one or more alphabetic `[a-zA-Z]+`
- followed by one or more degit between parentheses `\(\d+\)`
- followed by one or more space `\s*`
- followed then by equal `=`
- followed then by one or more space `\s*`
- followed then by one or more degit `\d+`
- all this between parentheses `\([a-zA-Z]+\(\d+\)\s*=\s*\d+\)`

with Pattern like this :

```
String[] texts = new String[]{"(text text (text) text)",
    "(F(1) = 44)",
    "(text text [text] text)",
    "[text text (text) text]"};
String regex = "\\([a-zA-Z]*\\(\\d+\\)\\s*=\\s*\\d+\\)";

for (String s : texts) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("There are match " + matcher.group());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match occurred");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
No match occurred
There are match (F(1) = 44)
No match occurred
No match occurred
```

## regex demo

Comment: thnks. Its really helped. But,String text = (text text (text) text);
 String text1 = (F(1) = 44);
 String text2 = (text text [text] text);
 String text3 = [text text (text) text];
 
 This all separate String and now you give text1 regex pattern.  Am tried other senarios but didnt work.

Comment: what did you mean @sathishanish i don't get you

Comment: @sathishanish if this separated text check my edit hope this can help you

Comment: sorry.Now you give regex is one scenario of (F(1) = 44) this pattern. I need to check this also pattern (()). In this open close having some text.

Comment: (text text (text) text)  This is one scenario.

Comment: @sathishanish so you mean `(())` shoud be matched? if yes then you have to use this `"\\([a-zA-Z]*\\(\\d*\\)\\s*=?\\s*\\d*\\)"` instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150580/discussion-between-sathish-anish-and-ycf-l).

Comment: @sathishanish sorry i can't use chat in my network if you have any question you can post it like a comment :)